# How to toggle between two different dropdown menus without having them both open at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two different dropdown options I'm using. One is for some search options, and the other is for a navigation menu.

Currently, I'm unable to open a single menu at one time. They both open, one on top of the other. I'm unable to figure out how to keep only one menu open at a time.

If the navigation menu is open and I click the search option, then the navigation menu should close. If I have the search option open and I click the navigation menu, then search should close.

How can I accomplish this with JavaScript?

```js
//icon switch
const hamburgerMenuBtnContainer = document.querySelector('.hamburger-toggle');
const hamburgerMenuBtn = document.querySelector('.hamburger-toggle i');
const magnifyingGlassBtnContainer = document.querySelector('.search-toggle');
const magnifyingGlassBtn = document.querySelector('.search-toggle i');

hamburgerMenuBtnContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
  hamburgerMenuBtn.classList.toggle('fa-x');
  hamburgerMenuBtn.classList.toggle('fa-bars');
});

magnifyingGlassBtnContainer.addEventListener('click', function() {
  magnifyingGlassBtn.classList.toggle('fa-x');
  magnifyingGlassBtn.classList.toggle('fa-magnifying-glass');
})
```

```css
.search-collapse {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  min-height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light shadow">
  <div class="container-fluid nav-container">
    <h3 class="logo">Logo Here</h3>
    <div class="navbar-right">
      <!-- Two -->
      <button class="btn border-0 collapsed nav-btn me-3" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#search-content">
        <div class="search-toggle">
          <div class="search">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>

      <!-- Three -->
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler collapsed nav-btn" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar-content">
        <div class="hamburger-toggle">
          <div class="hamburger">
            <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Nav Content -->
    <div class="collapse search-collapse" id="search-content">
      <h4>Search Options</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
      <h4>Navigation Options</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Should they close when clicking outside?

Comment: It would be a nice add on. If you'd like to add it, that would be great.